# encoding issue when exporting from dataframe in python to MS access

Tags: python, sql, pandas, encoding, jupyter

Dears,
i have a python script that have a query that reads from a DB , store the result in a Dataframe , then export it to MS access.
in the loop , it divides the result into 3 files ( each file has different month ) .
the issue in the column : LI_DESC , it have Arabic letter that shows correctly in jupyter , but it shows incorrect char when exported to access .
here is the columns showing correctly in jupyter:

[image]

here is the columns shown in access file:

[image]

python code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import accessdb
import pandas as pd
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('10.112.**.****', '1521', service_name='cdwn10g.hq')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='BI', password='BI', dsn=dsn_tns , encoding='utf-8')
sql_query= pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT MONTH1,LI_DESC,PORT,REGS_NUM,REG_DT,CTRY_CD,TAR_CD,UNS_QTY,UN_CD,KGN,KGG,CIF_AMT,CURCY_CD,CURCY_RT
FROM STTS.CDS
WHERE SUBSTR(REG_DT_G,1,6) BETWEEN to_number(extract(year from add_months(sysdate,-3)) || '' || to_char(add_months(sysdate,-3), 'MM')) AND to_number(extract(year from add_months(sysdate,-1)) || '' || to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'MM'))
ORDER BY PORT, REGS_NUM, REG_DT""",conn)
df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.now()
if not os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\nalkar\Documents\Python Scripts\RUNDATE'+today.strftime('%Y%m%d')) :
    os.makedirs(r'C:\Users\nalkar\Documents\Python Scripts\RUNDATE'+today.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
    months= df['MONTH1'].unique().tolist()
    for month in months:
        mydf=df.loc[df.MONTH1 == month]
        mydf.to_accessdb(r"C:\Users\nalkar\Documents\Python Scripts\RUNDATE"+today.strftime('%Y%m%d')+"\%s.accdb" %month, "Data")
        print('done')
else:
    print(r'directory already exist')
```

Comment: It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case. You should share a [mcve] (pictures are generally unwelcome). However. here's an incomplete example from highlighted line in the 2nd picture: `'Û…Ø±Ø³ÛŠØ¯'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf-8')` returns `'ۅرسۊد'`…

Comment: here are some example:
Ø¹Ø±ÙˆØ³Ù‡  ///or//

Ù„Ø¹Ø¨Ø© Ø­ØµØ§Ù„Ø©
///or//
Ø³ÙŠØ§Ø±Ø©